# gtsummary R package: how to add number of events for tbl_regression?

Tags: r, gtsummary

When creating a table using `tbl_regression()` from the gtsummary R package, how do you add the number of events using `add_nevent()` ?  When I run the example code from the `add_nevent()` help file, I am unable to get the N's to appear:

```
library(gtsummary)
data(trial)
add_nevent_ex <-
  glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_nevent()
add_nevent_ex
```

[image]

In contrast, when I run the example code from the help file for `add_nevent.tbl_uvregression()`, the N's appear correctly in the table.  Unfortunately, I need to use tbl_regression (and not tbl_uvregression) though because I need to adjust for multiple covariates for the actual problem I'm working on.

Comment: You should include  a) data and b) library calls for all packages needed. (I'm guessing most readers have no idea what the gtsummary package is supposed to support and what specifically the `tbl_regression` does. So if we were to attempt answering in this background of ignorance, we would need to have a dataset to work on. It's your responsibility to provide a method for getting one into our workspace. see [ask] and [MCVE] and search on "how to make a great reproducible example in R".

Comment: Hi @IRTFM ,  the example code in my post is fully reproducible, as long as you have the gtsummary package installed.  I know my question is very specific, but I have asked other questions about this package in the past and one of the authors has always replied with a great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in gtsummary v1.4.0, the `add_nevent()` function has been generalized to A) work with `tbl_regression` and `tbl_uvregression` obejcts, and B) has the ability to place Ns on the label and variable level rows. Review the help file here: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/dev/reference/add_nevent_regression.html (FYI, the `add_n()` has been updated similarly for `tbl_regression` objects in the dev version.)

```r
library(gtsummary)

add_nevent_ex <-
  glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_n() %>%
  add_nevent()
```

[image]